# freeradius refuses to start because it says OpenSSL is vulnerable

Tags: security, openssl, radius

I work with Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't start the `freeradius` deamon (freeradius-server-3.0.9). I have this error that I cannot solve:

```
Refusing to start with libssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014    
0x1000106f (1.0.1f release) (in range 1.0.1 dev - 1.0.1f release)
Security advisory CVE-2014-0160 (Heartbleed)
For more information see http://heartbleed.com
Once you have verified libssl has been correctly patched, set    
security.allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'
```

`dpkg -l | grep openssl`

```
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:i386                              2.12.23-12ubuntu2.2                                 i386         GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  openssl                                               1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                                  i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  python-openssl                                        0.13-2ubuntu6                                       i386         Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
```

`apt-cache policy freeradius`

```
freeradius:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1
  Version table:
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0:i386`

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1
  Version table: 
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1 0 
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l | grep libssl`

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -l|grep libssl
ii  libssl-dev:i386                                       1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                                  i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc                                            1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                                  all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                                      1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                                  i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1f is not fix ..

Comment: Don't use the comments for the output of the commands. [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy freeradius`

Comment: Or have you installed the server with this version: http://freeradius.org/download.html

Comment: And one more: `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0:i386`

Comment: Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1
  Version table:
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages

Comment: Please [EDIT] your question.

Comment: version of openssl: openssl1.0.1f is not fix ( that's the problem ) , I update and upgrade openssl ----> same erreur ' freeradius refuse to start with this version -----> I think I must remove the actual version and install the version openssl-1.0.1g ( is fix and not velnurable ) but how can I do it ??

Comment: Please start my commands and add the output into your question by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: It's ok , I'm editing my question

Comment: @LaasriReda how did you install freeradius?  From `apt-get` or from source, or some other method?

Comment: tar zxvf freeradius-server-3.0.9.tar.gz
cd freeradius-server-3.0.9
./configure –sysconfdir=/etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `freeradius` is doing, apparently is detecting purely on the version string returned by OpenSSL on the OS.  Unfortunately, that version string does NOT take into account Ubuntu or Debian revision numbers.

Ubuntu security updates are typically put in via a `-#ubuntu#` style changelog entry in the package, and the packages to install that have the security updates originate from the `RELEASE-security` repository, where `RELEASE` is the codename for the Ubuntu version you're on.

Because of this, we have to examine the specific CVE, and check the Ubuntu Security Team's CVE tracker.  [The page detailing the Heartbleed CVE (CVE-2014-0160) in the Ubuntu Security Team's tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0160.html) indicates that the following versions had patches applied to fix the OpenSSL Heartbleed issue:

- Precise: Fixed in package `openssl` package version `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12`
- Trusty: Fixed in package `openssl` package version `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2`

If you have pulled in all OpenSSL updates from the Security repositories, and have at least `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2` of OpenSSL installed (and your information provided says that `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15` is installed), you will be fine.

Provided the above matches your case, then you can follow the instructions that the error message provides you, and put into place this line, probably as part of the configuration files: `security.allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2014-0160'`

Comment: Mr Thomas , can you give me comands to install 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 instead of openssl.1.0.1f ... beauce after updating and upgarding ubuntu , openssl1.0.1f keep staying , so please give me the instructions to follow ( I'm beginer on linux ) ...Thank you

Comment: @LaasriReda Reread my answer.  Especially this phrase in it:  **"and your information provided says that 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 is installed"**.  You're already good to go.  The corresponding `libssl-dev` and `libssl` packages and such are provided by the same source package, so you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

These is a minor follow-up on @"Thomas Ward"'s answer.

The config file to edit is:

```
radiusd.conf
```

and the edit is:

```
security {
    [...]
    #allow_vulnerable_openssl = no
    allow_vulnerable_openssl = 'CVE-2016-6304'
    }
```